# Populating Spinners using Retrofit 1.9?

Tags: android, spinner, retrofit

Am looking sample program which could dynamically populating `Spinner` item from server using `Retrofit 1.9` but still I couldn't find any sample can someone share if there is any sample regarding this requirement or else share the method. 
How it should be done as am new for android bit struggling to find a solution thanks in advance!

Here is my spinneritem class:

```
public class MySpinnerItem {

    public MySpinnerItem(){

    }
    public MySpinnerItem(String text, Integer value) {
        Text = text;
        Value = value;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return Text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        Text = text;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return Value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        Value = value;
    }

    public String Text;
    public Integer Value;

}
```

Here is my spinner adapter:

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 25-11-2015.
 */
public class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MySpinnerItem> {

    private Context context;
    private List<MySpinnerItem> objects;
    public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MySpinnerItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(MySpinnerItem object) {
       this.objects.add(object);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MySpinnerItem getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setText(objects.get(position).getText());
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setText(objects.get(position).getText());
        return label;
    }
}
```

Here is the fragment where i set adapter for spinners:

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 23-11-2015.
 */

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.squareup.otto.Bus;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NewRequirements extends Fragment {
    Bus bus;
    MyListAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<MySpinnerItem> SbuList = new ArrayList<MySpinnerItem>();
        SbuList.add(new MySpinnerItem("Saravanan.R",1));
        SbuList.add(new MySpinnerItem("Yogeshwaran",2));
        SbuList.add(new MySpinnerItem("Sathesh",3));
        SbuList.add(new MySpinnerItem("Barath",4));
        SbuList.add(new MySpinnerItem("Deepak",5));
        SbuList.add(new MySpinnerItem("Venkat",6));
        SbuList.add(new MySpinnerItem("Meena",7));
        SbuList.add(new MySpinnerItem("Ram",8));
        SbuList.add(new MySpinnerItem("Jegan",9));

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_claim, container,
                false);
        final Button btnupdate;
        btnupdate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        final Spinner spSbuID = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spSbuID);
        final Spinner spBuID = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spBuID);
        final Spinner spSubBuID = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spSubBuID);
        final Spinner spServiceCategoryID = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spServiceCategoryID);
        final Spinner spServiceSubCategoryID = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spServiceSubCategoryID);
        final EditText txtRequirements=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtRequirements);

        MySpinnerAdapter myadapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,SbuList);
        spSbuID.setAdapter(myadapter);

        myadapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,SbuList);
        spBuID.setAdapter(myadapter);

        myadapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,SbuList);
        spSubBuID.setAdapter(myadapter);

        myadapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,SbuList);
        spServiceCategoryID.setAdapter(myadapter);

        myadapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,SbuList);
        spServiceSubCategoryID.setAdapter(myadapter);




        try{
            Object o;
            o = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("add");
            Log.v("FIND", o.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.v("FIND", ex.toString());
        }

     //   add.notify();

        btnupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LeadRequirementsView objLeadRequirementsView = new LeadRequirementsView();
                MySpinnerItem item;

                item = (MySpinnerItem)spSbuID.getSelectedItem();
                objLeadRequirementsView.setSbuID(item.getValue());
                objLeadRequirementsView.setSbuName(item.getText());

                item = (MySpinnerItem)spBuID.getSelectedItem();
                objLeadRequirementsView.setBuID(item.getValue());
                objLeadRequirementsView.setBuName(item.getText());

                item = (MySpinnerItem)spSubBuID.getSelectedItem();
                objLeadRequirementsView.setSubBuID(item.getValue());
                objLeadRequirementsView.setSubBuName(item.getText());

                item = (MySpinnerItem)spServiceCategoryID.getSelectedItem();
                objLeadRequirementsView.setServiceCategoryID(item.getValue());
                objLeadRequirementsView.setServiceCategoryName(item.getText());

                item = (MySpinnerItem)spServiceSubCategoryID.getSelectedItem();
                objLeadRequirementsView.setServiceSubCategoryID(item.getValue());
                objLeadRequirementsView.setServiceSubCategoryName(item.getText());

                objLeadRequirementsView.setDescription(txtRequirements.getText().toString());

                Add add;

                add = (Add)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("add");
                add.updateListView(objLeadRequirementsView);
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }

        });
        return view;
    }



}
```

My doubt is i have done it using dummy data but i need to bind the json response from the server to my spinner how come i do this.

Comment: At first google for using Retrofit in your application, how we could retrieve the data from server, then we can set it in Spinner. So, may I know which part you are unable to understand?

Comment: from yesterday only i have started using retrofit successfully implemented login response from server now i just want i know i can retrieve data using pojo's but i don't know how to set it in spinner

Comment: You are able to getting the data in Pojo, right?

Comment: yaaa i could but i am bit confused how to set it to spinners

Comment: Find the posted answer, and let me know any issue is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, is a sample for setting the spinner

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
List<String> data;

data = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        data.add("Data " + (i + 1));

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here data is a dummy data , in your case it will be dummy data.

Comment: k i"l try it and let u know and one more doubt why do we need custom converter as we are having default converters in retrofit

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran Can you give me example , of converter because I never used converters.

Comment: like jsontostring converter i have seen in some sample programs and one more doubt i assume that u may be experienced android developer is it reliable to use network lib like retrofit

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran yup, it provides so many extra things, we can use without brain storming in coding. And its simple to use.

Comment: @NigamParto you should  continue to help beginners like us thank you so much and il try the following snippet and let you know

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran Sure, and if it helps, accept and vote up the answer.

Comment: am trying to make cache response from server for that i use okhttp2.4+retrofit 1.9 how make cache response during offline

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran Sorry but I dont have any idea related to caching the response. But whether the code is working for spinner?

Comment: regarding spinner i need to make use of custom adapter then how should i do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97475/discussion-between-nigam-patro-and-m-yogeshwaran).

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran can you come to chat?

Answer (score 2):

first create theretrofitapi interface

```
/**
 * reCreated by goodlife on 1/11/2016.
 */
import java.util.List;


import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.client.Response;
import retrofit.http.Field;
import retrofit.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.POST;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 11/5/2015.
 */
public interface RetrofitInternetApi {

    //@FormUrlEncoded, we have to write this if we want to send post data to the server.
    //@POST, because we are using an HTTP Post request we have written this.
    // Inside it we have the URL of the script that will be receiving the post request.
    // Note that the URL is excluding the root URL. And we have defined the root URL  in our MainActivity.
    //@Field(“key”) String variable inside key we have to write what we have written inside $_POST[‘key’] in our script.
    // And we have to specify it for all the values we are going to send.

    //Callback<Response> callback it is also inside the retrofit library. It will receive the output from the server.

    //But this is only an interface and the method is abstract.
    //We will define the method inside fetchDepartmentName() method that is declared inside MainActivity.java.

    @GET("/getDepartmentName.php")
    public void getDepartmentName(Callback<List<DepartmentNoRealm>> response);

}
```

then create the function

```
  private void fetchDepartmentName(){
//Creating a rest adapter
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
                .build();

        //Creating an object of our api interface
        RetrofitInternetApi retrofitInternetApi = restAdapter.create(RetrofitInternetApi.class);
            //While the app fetched data we are displaying a progress dialog
            final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);



            //Defining the method
            retrofitInternetApi.getDepartmentName(new Callback<List<DepartmentNoRealm>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(List<DepartmentNoRealm> list, Response response) {
                    //Dismissing the loading progressbar
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Log.d("JSON  LIST",list.toString());
                    //Storing the data in our list
                    departmentNoRealmList = list;

                    //Calling a method to show the list
                      showListinSpinner();            }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    //you can handle the errors here
                }
            });
        }
```

then create a class model

```
package myafya.safaricom.co.ke.myafya.model.realm;

/**
 * Created by 001557 on 1/13/2016.
 */
public class DepartmentNoRealm {
    public int departmentID;
    public String departmentName;
    public String departmentURLimage;

    public int getDepartmentID() {
        return departmentID;
    }

    public void setDepartmentID(int departmentID) {
        this.departmentID = departmentID;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    public String getDepartmentURLimage() {
        return departmentURLimage;
    }

    public void setDepartmentURLimage(String departmentURLimage) {
        this.departmentURLimage = departmentURLimage;
    }
}
```

now the code showList in Spinner

```
//Our method to show list
    private void showListinSpinner(){
        //String array to store all the book names
        String[] items = new String[departmentNoRealmList.size()];

        //Traversing through the whole list to get all the names
        for(int i=0; i<departmentNoRealmList.size(); i++){
            //Storing names to string array
            items[i] = departmentNoRealmList.get(i).getDepartmentName();
        }

        //Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        //setting adapter to spinner
        spinnerDepartments.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Creating an array adapter for list view

    }
```

Then SHARE IT AND MAKE IT EASY

MY JSON WAS

```
[
  {
    "departmentID": "1",
    "departmentName": "Enterprise Business Unit (EBU)",
    "departmentURLimage": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKOZmGNAA08NbHwRJrloAouWqs6r4x7BGXY4k-ULWiHuPEobHI"
  },
  {
    "departmentID": "2",
    "departmentName": "Consumer Business Unit (CBU)",
    "departmentURLimage": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0IAFhZ52KiG_0ck5VbBxweZWf_MEA9eRmgHAEr6CG-rUG_a2QEQ"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        try {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
            Call<List<People>> call = service.getYear(user_id);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<People>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<List<People>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    posts = response.body();
            String[] s =new String[posts.size()];
                    for(int i=0;i<posts.size();i++)
                    {
                       s[i]= posts.get(i).getYear();
                        final ArrayAdapter a = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);
                        a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
                        Branch.setAdapter(a);
                    }                    
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) { }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
               }

}
```

Comment: add some explaination